# FileLoadException and strong assembly signing

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, filenotfoundexception, strongname, strong-named-key

I have an assembly which is referencing couple of other assemblies. Everything was working fine and then I went ahead and strongly signed all of the assemblies. The assembly contains entity designer and generated entities and context objects. Now any change made in the designer results in error and I can't get rid of it. The errors are listed below. Any help would be much appreciated.

Error   1   Failed to resolve assembly reference. The path 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\WindowsBase\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\WindowsBase.dll' must be either local to this computer or part of your trusted zone. If you have downloaded this template, you may need to 'Unblock' it using the properties page for the template file in Windows Explorer..

Error   2   There was a problem loading the assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'

Error   3   There was a problem loading the assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll'

Error   4   There was a problem loading the assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'

Error   5   There was a problem loading the assembly 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll'

The error and stack trace for errors 2-5 are similar like:
The following Exception was thrown:
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515)
File name: 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.Entity.dll' ---> System.NotSupportedException: An attempt was made to load an assembly from a network location which would have caused the assembly to be sandboxed in previous versions of the .NET Framework. This release of the .NET Framework does not enable CAS policy by default, so this load may be dangerous. If this load is not intended to s